# What does MSC in "// appease MSC" comments mean?

Tags: c++

I occasionally run across `// appease MSC` in C++ comments, e.g. [here](http://aramis.obspm.fr/~alma/ASDM/SFIASDM-2007-05-B/c++/testerror.html):

```
const int& Array::operator[](int offSet) const
{
  int mysize = GetitsSize();
  if (offSet >= 0 && offSet < GetitsSize())
    return pType[offSet];
  throw xBoundary();
  return pType[offSet]; // to appease MSC!
}
```

What does MSC stand for ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and pasting the actual code here. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author means Microsoft's compiler, more formally known as MSVC.

Comment: Interesting.  The tone of the comment seems snarky.  Does that mean that the author of the comment considers the line of code to be unnecessary, except to satisfy the compiler.  In other words, does the comment suggest that the compiler is imposing an unnecessary burden on the developer?

Comment: Yes, it's a snarky comment, but there's a reason for the snark.  In the example you provide, the "return" statement at the end is unreachable.  Yet some non-specific version of MSVC requires it anyway, apparently.  Although my preference would be to rework the logic in the function so that there's only one return statement, at the end, by making the throw statement conditional (based on the "if" condition).